# Angular Material 2 - Expansion Panel Tracking

Tags: angular, accordion, angular-material2

I have a an angular material expansion panels which are being loaded via an array of objects.  I need the key of the object chosen when the expansion panel header is chosen (clicked). So I can then use this chosen object to load data within the panel itself?

Not sure where to start?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details, and some actual code, in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Not sure what code add.